# Enforce Plain HTML Element Passed as Children in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a React component which enforces that its children are plain HTML elements (such as `<p>...</p>`) and **not** React components (such as `<SomeComponent/>`)

Here's some code I've tried, to no avail

```
import React from "react"

interface ITooltipProps {
  // Goal is to require a plain HTML child here, i.e. <p>...</p>, and error if we get anything else
  // children: React.ReactElement<JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]>;

  // This doesn't work because the JSX.IntrinsicElements map just returns props, not the element type
  // children: JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements];
  
  // This doesn't work because it's just asking for a react component that can take props of an HTML element (all of which are optional)
  children: React.ReactElement<JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]>;
}

export function Tooltip({
  children
}: ITooltipProps) {
  return (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
  )
}

// An element which doesn't return a plain HTML child
const F = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
    </>
  )
}

const x = (
    // Expect <F/> to error, since F isn't returning a plain HTML object / is returning a fragment
  <Tooltip>
    <F/>
  </Tooltip>
)
```

([Here's a link to a TS playground with the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQBUIIAbGYMABRzABnOAG9ScOAHpJcAOIQUHOMGEwIcIgEcArsCJwUcMBxRU4ACRYBZADJw0AC2AcAJnAe0kAGmUA6JL5wADxgAHy+EUGSYT4olG60OFDKmHAA7owA5kjwcQCeME6UmXBIHIJI4lIyjs4uRJQAXIjEML7I6DAAohxIIEjUQQBSAMoAGr5M1FBUgsBoPX0DMIIA2gDWSHkQqaMTUzAzlHMLvf3UggC6oQDc5BLScCxOwi4QSIKUAOTwadDrcAARkg0ChtBU4IVGHtJtNZvNFucVnAQCgwHAAFbg+BEGDaKDHIwCQQ+SgQeBQ0pnZaQvJgSoPGpOVwNZowg5HE6I5ZrTbbXbjWGHeGnJYXS53CRVR7PFRwN4fb6-f5AkFgiHAGBfYRYwS5QTrKglTDQAwaVr2XCQSg0wooeCgyiQlCbIkQIRwHYGJ2WWxUsXwAAUiiUXrSTkcBn07u4EEoigAlFVaiyBs0Ohh2q1uYN2XDjgjqRcNlsvXnhQXRUirrdSABfchIAAekFgcEw2koGGAcae7C4PEDYgkKfqA3rzVY-e4fGJCdEVVx+KdgaqEiCLmAADdQmuJPuRKOGg398FJJud1Ukw3SI8AIJOsoB9IRhzy96fH7mvEEs3GUw+tYdijqQaBxnqcAAGJwAAvHAgbzjBoQLhIS6-qup5BLup6YWE5hlBwEBRGEe64aEADq0CuMR2H7lEtHXuQYHHPATawfBe6PF0LYgvAQSQZIyFqKUUBJD4cxdow0EqEq37Lkaf4mGYvp2BAgIYrxUjKMIaGUAphjYCgmRIlUQRsJwM60euAm0VE5kDiRCZAA))

Am wondering if anybody knows how to enforce that a component's children are "primitive" HTML elements, as opposed to react components – thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

Rendered JSX has a return type of `JSX.Element` no matter what it contains. So plain html, a fragment, or a rendered component all have the same type. Which means you can't use types to constrain it in this way.

[See this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxxgGm)